# Linking symbols to fixed memory addresses in Windows DLL

Tags: windows, pointers, dll, linker, embedded

I have an unusual situation where I need to create a DLL which declares some symbols to be pre-determined memory locations.  It's an embedded system with a bunch of modules using shared memory which always starts at the same location.

The C source files all include a bunch of boilerplate that looks like this:

```
__declspec(dllimport) struct shmem_block {
    unsigned char  dum0000001[4952];                                              
    int            _yallahabibi[1];
} arftest;
```

To make this work, I need to compile and link it with a DLL which declares arftest to point to a specific memory location.  How can create such a DLL?  Using C, I can declare a pointer and make it point somewhere, but how do you make a variable name (symbol) point to a memory location?

Answer (score 0):

Because of memory virtualisation and protection in windows, I believe that you will have to implement a *device driver* to access *physical* memory directly.

Normally location of a data object to a specific location requires compiler extensions and linker support; so that will be toolchain specific if supported at all.

In the general case, you would use a pointer rather than instantiate an object; e.g.:

```
volatile my_struct* my_object = (my_struct*)0x00008000;
```

Then access the data through the pointer; e.g.:

```
my_object->some_member = 0x00080 ;
```

Alternatively, in C++ you can use *placement new*.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you made in sharing that, but as I said in the question pointers are not useful in this situation.  I can't change the boiler-plate code in all the source files, so it's the struct variable arftest that needs to point to the memory location and not a pointer to a struct.

Comment: With respect, you did not explicitly say you couldn't change the code or that pointers were not useful - you simply suggested you know how to set a pointer. If you cannot modify the code you cannot change the location of `arftest`, but you don't need to.  `arftest` is of no use to you, it is the structure `shmem_block` that is of interest; you simply need an instance of a `shmem_block` appropriately located, e.g.: `volatile struct shmem_block* my_shared_memory = (struct shmem_block*)0x00008000 ;`